# What is the distrubition of the forces on the hand-scale

Tags: forces, scales

[image]

In the picture above, I am applying 32 33 Newtons of force if I am not wrong. But, what is the forces on my both hands? Do they share it equally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each hand is pulling the full reading of the scale, the hand pulling the hook is pulling the reading on the scale, and the scale is pulling the other hand with an equal force.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the scales as the system it has three external forces acting on it.

The hand at the top is applying an upward  force on the scales, $F_{\rm top}$.

The hand at the bottom is applying a downward  force on the scales, $F_{\rm bottom}$.

The Earth is applying a downward force on the scales, $F_{\rm Earth}$, (weight of scales).

The scales are not accelerating so taking down as the positive direction  $F_{\rm Earth}+ F_{\rm bottom} - F_{\rm top} =0$.

The reading on the scales is the force, in kg force units, exerted on the scale by the top hand.

Imagine the bottom hand not being there then the reading on the scale would be the weight of (most of) the scale.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but the scale is actually horizontal( see the carpet below) and hands are pulling it in horizontal plane.  To right and left lets say. The photo is taken so that it is a birds look to the scale. Anyway the answer is clear.